# What's the meaning of using append on sub-slices with spread operator?

Tags: go, slice

I am confused about how the following code works, especially what is the purpose of "..."

```
array = append(array[:i], array[i+1:]...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
a = append(a[:i], a[i+1:]...)
```

creates a new slice by removing the item at position `i` in `a`, by combining the items from 0 to i (not included), and from i+1 to the end.

Your second question is what is the purpose of `...`. `append` accepts a slice as first argument, and an unlimited number of arguments, all with a type [assignable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to the type of its elements.

[`append`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) is defined as

```
func append(slice []Type, elems ...Type) []Type
```

Writing

```
a = append(a[:i], a[i+1:]...)
```

is equivalent as writing

```
a = append(a[:i], a[i+1], a[i+2], a[i+3], a[i+4]) //and so on, until the end of the slice.
```

Using `a[i+1:]...` is basically a shorthand syntax, as the Go spec describes in https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters:

> If f is variadic with a final parameter p of type ...T, then within f the type of p is equivalent to type []T. If f is invoked with no actual arguments for p, the value passed to p is nil. Otherwise, the value passed is a new slice of type []T with a new underlying array whose successive elements are the actual arguments, which all must be assignable to T

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cqeMkemn62)

Answer (score 1):

```
array = append(array[:i], array[i+1:]...)
```

is removing an element at index `i`

but another thing to point out is that slice is backed by an underlying array. For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    myArray := [6]int {1,2,3,4,5,6}

    mySlice := myArray[:]

    fmt.Println("myArray before append: ", myArray)

    i := 3
    mySlice = append(mySlice[:i], mySlice[i+1:]...)

    fmt.Println("mySlice after append: ", mySlice)
    fmt.Println("myArray after append: ", myArray)
}
```

Result:

```
myArray before append:  [1 2 3 4 5 6]
mySlice after append:  [1 2 3 5 6]
myArray after append:  [1 2 3 5 6 6]
```

[goplayground](https://play.golang.org/p/oDfbI-gBir)

In the underlying `[1,2,3]` stayed in place, that data never go moved anywhere, while `[5,6]` which were given by `b[i+1]` were appended to `[1,2,3]`, and thus overwrote `[3,4]`; the other `[6]` stayed in place.

Even though you get different copy of a slice the underlying array will be the same*, this makes append a much more efficient operation then if the whole underlying array had to be copied over!

*If underlying array exceeds it's capacity, a new larger array will be allocated and values from old array would be copied to the new array, but this will never happen when removing an element.

Answer (score 0):

Built-in func [append](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) is Variadic Function.

To pass slice argument to any variadic function, you have to use `...`

Go lang spec: [Passing arguments to ... parameters](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters)

> If f is variadic with final parameter type ...T, then within the
>   function the argument is equivalent to a parameter of type []T. At
>   each call of f, the argument passed to the final parameter is a new
>   slice of type []T whose successive elements are the actual arguments,
>   which all must be assignable to the type T. The length of the slice is
>   therefore the number of arguments bound to the final parameter and may
>   differ for each call site.

---

This line would give you a result value removing position `i`.

```
array = append(array[:i], array[i+1:]...)
```

Let's say, we have

```
array := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
i := 3

fmt.Println("Original slice:", array)

part1 := array[:i]
part2 := array[i+1:]
fmt.Println("part1:", part1)
fmt.Println("part2:", part2)

array = append(array[:i], array[i+1:]...)
fmt.Println("Result slice:", array)
```

Output:

```
Original slice: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
part1: [1 2 3]
part2: [5 6 7]
Result slice: [1 2 3 5 6 7]
```

Play Link: https://play.golang.org/p/_cIk0VcD6w

Comment: So what that line is doing is making a new slice by concatenating elements 0 through i-1 with elements starting with i+1 and continuing to the end of the slice. In other words, the effect is to delete element `i` from `array` (by making a new slice; it doesn't happen in place).

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `...` is to save you typing individual elements as the `append` method takes first argument as slice and then variable number of arguments for elements to be appended.

i.e. You actually need to call append as

`append(sliceName[:i], array[i+1], array[i+2], array[i+3], array[i+4])`

but to avoid typing long list of elements, you can simply use `...` after the slice or array to spread it as individual elements to be passed as arguments.